# Remove menu item on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, menu, menuitem

In my Blackberry application, I have screen with few menu items (created by myself in ***makeMenu()***).
On this screen, sometimes I should remove two of this menu items.
But ***menu.deleteItem()*** method does not work.

How i can remove menu item in application menu, without recreate new instance of screen? Is it real for already constructed menu? Or mb I should refresh menu/screen someway?

Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The menu is drawn at the point it's selected so all I do is set conditions on anything that's not static, example below:

```
protected void makeMenu( Menu menu, int instance ) {
    menu.add(staticMenuItem);
    if (condition) menu.add(dynamicMenuItem);
}
```

Comment: Is this what you're after or do you need a visible menu to have items appearing and disappearing while the user watches?

Comment: But what i should do, if my screen already shown with set of menu items and my condition is changed? How can i remove menu items from menu without screen repush?

Comment: Ah so you really do need people to witness the items vanish. menu.deleteItem is not fit for that purpose. What you could possibly do it override keyDown so that when the menu button is pressed your app loads a custom field. Then you would have much more control. Or if the case is rare enough to use conditions on makemenu you could simply display a dialog to explain why the menu selected couldn't work e.g. "Sorry this item is not available offline"