# Blackberry delete menu item

Tags: blackberry, menuitem

I have mainscreen with 5 menus and after a certain action I need to delete 2 of them in a method that peforms the action, can I delete menu items programetically ?

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4538330/593709)

Comment: Check `Menu` class documentation http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Menu.html

Comment: @Prince Charming: Yes you can delete the menu items on the current screen; see the answer in your post;

Answer (score 0):

Run this sample code:

```
public class Abc extends MainScreen
{   
    ButtonField click;

    MenuItem saveMenu;

    public Abc() 
    {       
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() 
    {   
        saveMenu=new MenuItem("Save", 100, 101);
        addMenuItem(saveMenu);

        click=new ButtonField("click");
        click.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() 
        {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
            {
                removeTheMenu(saveMenu);
            }
        });
        add(click);


    }   

    public void removeTheMenu(MenuItem menuItem) 
    {           
        Screen screen=Ui.getUiEngine().getActiveScreen();
        Menu menu=screen.getMenu(0);//Gives the Menu list of active screen only;
        for(int i=0;i<menu.getSize();i++)
        {
            if(menu.getItem(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(menuItem.toString()))
            {
                removeMenuItem(menuItem);
                Status.show("Removed Successfully", 1000);
            }       
        }       
    }   
}
```

This code may help you;